# Is it possible to store an iterator?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

For example, say I have a const_iterator:

```
QHash<const QString, QPair<const Node, double> >::const_iterator citer =  adjNodeHash.begin();
```

Can I then store citer in a data structure (containing many iterators) and re-use it later, with it still referring to the same place I left off the next time I use it? (assuming I update it accordingly/use a reference to it when I am incrementing it)

I ask this because I have used this approach yet am getting some undefined bahaviour and am wondering if this is the culprit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the invalidation rules of the container, but generally storing iterators/pointers is not a good idea. Better to just store the key (in the case of a map).

Comment: You could save an iterator, but know that if you modify the container (insert, remove, etc) you're likely to invalidate it.

Comment: Loosely speaking they follow similar rules to pointers: ie are vulnerable to invalidation.

Comment: _"I ask this because I have used this approach yet am getting some undefined bahaviour and am wondering if this is the culprit."_ We're actually not able to diagnose this, unless you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. Also note, answers might come up different for [`c++ std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) and Qt iterator declarations (that's why I added the tag).

Answer (score 6):

Iteration invalidation rules for `std` containers are described in the standard.  `QHash` will also have some iterator invalidation rules in its documentation (hopefully!).

A stored iterator remains valid until invalidated.  Most hash maps invalidate their iterators when they "rehash", which happens when they grow past a certain bound.

In practice, it is probably a bad idea to store an iterator into a hash map over a period in which elements are added or removed from it.  Maintaining that iterator as valid will take constant maintenance and error checking, adding overhead to every use of that hash map, and any errors developing may not immediately show up, and the error that happens won't occur near the spot where the mistake is made.

On top of that, if you ever swap out what hash container you are using, the details of the iterator invalidation rules are going to be different.  This makes refactoring in the future more painful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I feel like its important now to mention that the hash will not change during this process.  I'm basically using an iterative DFS, and want to keep track of which adjacent node I left off from previously searching, for each vertex. So I am storing this extra variable (the iterator) on the stack along with the vertex.

Anyway I'm getting the general idea that it's a bad idea to store iterators from all these comments, so I'll stick with boring old integers instead.